# Custom label in field value of custom settings

Tags: custom-field, customlabel

I have some custom settings to send custom message in chat after few seconds. Because, the system is multilanguage and multicountry, I need to send messages in the customer's language. Is it possible to put a custom label in a field of a custom settings? I don't need any code, it's all done in standard pages.

Comment: please put some additional details about this question. it is very broad right now. Please visit [Ask] section to learn more

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I've just edited the question.